# Some interesting things to do

Tags: magic-items, monsters

I'm running my second game for my group ever, and I like doing fun and interesting things for them. One of the things I've been thinking about is them opening up a bag, or a chest, or a portable tower, or something like that, and seeing a bunch of rust monsters... thinking to themselves what the hell?! They will also find a bag with a bunch of leather armors and clubs labeled "enchanting :)" which is also something my group would do given the chance (I've been playing with them since high school, loooong time ago).

I designed an enchanting system for them to use this game, but part of the campaign is that they used to be a high level group but were sent back 50 years, so they will wake up with all this stuff they won't know anything about. One of the things I wanted to do, and something I know the group would figure out how to exploit, is rust monsters for recycling magic items.

A portable hole won't work, a bag of holding won't work, and I don't want to just give them a ritual to summon one because that's boring and will be overly exploited. I want that surprise factor, that amusement factor, and I want the joy of them figuring out what they eventually figured out before they were sent back.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour] and the [help]; they're a useful introduction to the site. Please tag the question with the system/edition you're using, so that answers address your specific situation.

Comment: Help is much more forthcoming and specific if the question is *really* clear. I'm not sure exactly what ideas are needed here. Is this a rust monster question? A magic item creation question?

Comment: Hi Squirrlejester! I'm voting to close this question - but just so it can get cleaned up and clarified! I just want to expand a little on what's expected - we are really focused on offering concrete answers, not discussion. So you need to focus your question a little tighter so we can give you a concrete answer. Do that and specify your system and we'll be all over this, I'm sure!

Comment: I think the question is clear. They want some "portal" which the players can access the rust monsters to use as a recycling bin.

Comment: @GMNoob If that's what they want, specifically, we can wait for them to say so and make it clear to everyone. Otherwise we're just going to get bad answers based on various misunderstandings.

Answer (score -2):

It depends how whimsical you want to get.

On the one hand, you can go back to the source of the Rust [monster as a plastic toy.](http://diterlizzi.com/home/owlbears-rust-monsters-and-bulettes-oh-my/) And have them either find a giant back of toys, or shrink to toy sized.

[image: Home of the Original Rust Monster]

On the other hand, you can get inspiration from the origin of the Humonculi, and have them find a jar with paintings of rust monsters on the side, which is worshiped by a town as being filled with tiny versions of the creatures.

[image: Shiny happy tiny people!]

Comment: I meant something in-game.